# How to count consecutive values of an ArrayList in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of type `Boolean` and I want to count consecutive occurrences of True or False.

My looping code works, but I am confused how to deal with the first element. I am trying to do the following:

```
 for(int i=0;i< Answers.size();i++) {
  if(Answers.get(i-1).booleanValue()= = Answers.get(i).booleanValue()) 
  ...
```

For `i=0` I get of course `-1=0`

If I start from `i=1` I leave out the first element

So how I can count them?

Comment: Your question is not really clear, what are you trying to achieve? In addition variables name should begin with lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is: there might be **several** sections like that. So you would need something more complicated. In that sense:

The first step is to define what exactly you have to "output" here. Assume you got:

```
true, true, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, true
```

What should bee the result? Do you just want to know:

```
true: 2 (because there are is one subsequence with 2 values)
```

or

```
true: 2, 3 (because you got two sequences, one with 2, one with 3 values)
```

Meaning: you have to clarify your requirements to exactly understand **what** your code has to do; before you should even think about the "how to do that"!

And on the specific question: you simply need a special check, such as

```
if (i == 0) {
 then of course you can't do i--
```

But as said: that only helps with your current loop; but it doesn't help you solving the real issue. Because you haven't even defined what you want to do yet!

Comment: if I do i=0 i<Answers.size()-1 ? and check if element(i)=element(i+1) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an state machine for that - you need to remember last answer and repetition count, which you reset when answer change to opposite value. like this:

```
public class CountBooleans {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[] answers = new boolean[20];

        answers[16] = true;
        answers[17] = true;
        answers[18] = true;

        countConsecutiveRepetitions(answers);
    }

    private static void countConsecutiveRepetitions(boolean[] answers) {
        boolean lastAnswer = answers[0];
        int repetitionCount = 0;

        for (boolean answer : answers) {
            if (answer == lastAnswer) {
                repetitionCount++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("There was: " + lastAnswer + " * " + repetitionCount);
                lastAnswer = answer;
                repetitionCount = 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("There was: " + lastAnswer + " * " + repetitionCount);
    }
}
```

will print:

```
There was: false * 16
There was: true * 3
There was: false * 1
```

Answer (score 1):

My java code that counts number of cosecutive occurrencies in list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Boolean> fruit = new ArrayList<>();
        fruit.addAll(Arrays.asList(true, true, true, true, false, false, false, false, true,true,false,false,true,true,false));

        int trueCount = 0, falseCount = 0;
        List<Integer> trueCounts = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> falseCounts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fruit.size();) {
            Boolean value = fruit.get(i);
            while (i < fruit.size() && fruit.get(i)) {
                trueCount++;
                i++;
            }
            while (i < fruit.size() && !fruit.get(i)) {
                falseCount++;
                i++;
            }
            trueCounts.add(trueCount);
            falseCounts.add(falseCount);
            trueCount=0;
            falseCount=0;
        }
        System.out.println(trueCounts);
        System.out.println(falseCounts);
    }
```

Prints :

```
[4, 2, 2]
[4, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the first problem, about the starting point, try the following code, which will compare all the pair values from consecutive positions: `(0, 1), (1, 2) ... (n-2, n-1)`, where `n = answers.size()`.

```
for(int i = 1; i < answers.size(); i++) {
    if(answers.get(i-1).booleanValue() == answers.get(i).booleanValue()) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Now, the `...` is more complicated. You have to keep track of changes between `true` and `false` consecutive values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer,

```
for(int i=0;i< Answers.size();i++)
    {
        if (i > 0) {
          if(Answers.get(i-1).booleanValue()==Answers.get(i).booleanValue())
          {

          }
        }
    }
```

let me know if it works for you. I also have some other ways to solve this problem.